# CVXPY chaining constraints issue

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy

I am running CVXPY package. When I added the following to the existing, workable constraints, the "Exception: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint" error raises. What's wrong? Is the matrix element-wise multiplication not allowed in this case?

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

A = a matrix with shape (20,)
x1 = cp.Variable(20, integer = True)

constraints = [...,
               np.multiply((A - 4), x1) >= np.zeros(20)]
```

Comment: So your constraints are like `(A[i] - 4)*x1[i] >= 0` for all `i`?

Comment: @swag2198 yes, I want to do element-wise mutiplication

Comment: Did you try with `-(np.diag(A - 4)  @  x1) <= np.zeros(20)`?